# How to create a function with parameters and a loop inside in R?

Tags: r

I want to create vector of 365 elements equal to

```
fCAT[i]<-seasonality[i]+beta0+beta1*exp(-gamma*day[i])+beta2*gamma*exp(-gamma*day[i])
```

where beta0, beta1, beta2 and gamma are unknown parameters. Next I have to optimise the parameters by minimising `(sum(fCAT)-1000)^2`. I was thinking about using a loop inside a function but I don't know how to define it so that the parameters are interpreted correctly and not as strings. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your function as:

```
f <- function(beta) {

    gamma <- beta[4]
    fCAT <- seasonality + beta[1] + 
        beta[2]*exp(-gamma*day) + 
        beta[3]*gamma*exp(-gamma*day)

    (sum(fCAT) - 1000)^2
}
```

Which you should be able to optimise using:

```
optim(rep(0, 4), f)
```

Comment: You should probably be careful with the results - `beta1` and `beta2` aren't identified by your objective function. If you factorise it to `fCAT=seasonality+beta0+(beta1+beta2*gamma)*exp(-gamma*day)` you'll see that multiple values of `beta1` and `beta2` can give the same optimum.

Answer (score 1):

If fCAT and day are observed then this is just a non-linear least squares problem that you can use the `nls` function to solve.

Comment: `fCAT` is not observed, it is defined as above, only `day` and `seasonality` are known.

Comment: @Hanna, I think you can still use `nls` by setting fCAT to 1000 for all observations, since that is the criteria that you are optimizing against.  `nls` optimizes the parameters based on the squared difference between the predicted values (fCAT in your case) and the observed values, so using 1000 as observed gives the same difference that you show in the question.

Comment: `nls` is probably the better option, since it will also give you estimated of your parameter uncertainties. I'm not sure it will handle unidentified parameters, but I suspect that's not actually what you want.

Comment: The criteria is `(sum(fCAT) - 1000)^2` not `sum((fCAT - 1000)^2)` so setting fCAT to 1000 won't help. At first I didn't notice the error in your code, pete, but after this small correction I get satisfactory results.

Comment: @Hanna, you should probably "Accept" Pete's answer as the one that works for you, as well as giving him an upvote.

Comment: @Hanna, you still need to be careful with the results - the values you get for `beta1` and `beta2` won't be unique.